# why (self: Runnable =>) in scala compiles?

Tags: function, scala

```
/** A marker indicating that a `java.lang.Runnable` provided to `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`
 * wraps a callback provided to `Future.onComplete`.
 * All callbacks provided to a `Future` end up going through `onComplete`, so this allows an
 * `ExecutionContext` to special-case callbacks that were executed by `Future` if desired.
 */
trait OnCompleteRunnable {
  self: Runnable =>
}
```

When I check the source code of Future in scala, I couldn't understand why self:Runnable => above compiles.
I know the symbol => can be used in method parameter as call by name, also it can be used to define function. The code above seems like defining a function, but it puzzles me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This syntax denotes an [explicitly typed self reference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/explicitly-typed-self-references.html). It essentially means that whatever extends `OnCompleteRunnable` must also extend `Runnable`.

You may wonder how does that differ from plain inheritance:

```
trait OnCompleteRunnable extends Runnable
```

In short, the difference is that self typed reference is just a type constraint. It does not establish a subtyping relation so `OnCompleteRunnable` cannot implement or override anything from `Runnable`. So it's something like a weaker form of inheritance.